# XAMPP Apache is running out of "resources" "working threads"

Tags: php, apache, resources, xampp, worker

I have a very mysterious problem with my Apache Server in XAMPP. I have a PHP script which downloads different contents from a website, it has multiple     parallel requests.

The script does not have any programming errors and is running perfect on my other server.

It seems like the server is running out of "resources". I dont know which resource is missing, the script stops with errors like:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\response.php on line 39
Warning: (null)(): 26 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
Warning: (null)(): 30 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
Warning: (null)(): 53 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
Warning: (null)(): 97 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
```

The server has enough free RAM and CPU available, which is correct assigned in the PHP script too.

The PHP.ini is the same as on my other server, so I dont think this seems to be the problem.

I have cleared all my logs and run the script once, this was in my log after that:

**PHP error log:**

```
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 6: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 5 and body in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\ice2.php on line 98
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): &lt;/body&gt; in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\ice2.php on line 98
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string():        ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\ice2.php on line 98
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 7: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 3 and html in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\ice2.php on line 98
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): &lt;/html&gt; in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\ice2.php on line 98
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string():        ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\ice2.php on line 98
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 8: parser error : Premature end of data in tag html line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\ice2.php on line 98
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string():  in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\ice2.php on line 98
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\ice2.php on line 98
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:38 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function children() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\response.php on line 39
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 643 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1314 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1357 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1400 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1500 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1522 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1544 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1601 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1623 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1645 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1667 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1689 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1711 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1755 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1777 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1799 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1847 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1869 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1926 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1974 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 643 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1314 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1357 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1400 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1500 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1522 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1544 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1601 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1623 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1645 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1667 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1689 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1711 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1755 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1777 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1799 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1847 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1869 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
[18-Apr-2016 16:55:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  (null)(): 1926 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0
```

**Apache Error log:**

```
[Mon Apr 18 16:54:50.074934 2016] [mpm_winnt:warn] [pid 177468:tid 216] AH00445: ThreadsPerChild of 100000 exceeds ThreadLimit of 1920, decreasing to match matches the server name 
[Mon Apr 18 16:54:50.137334 2016] [core:warn] [pid 177468:tid 216] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Apr 18 16:54:50.496135 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 177468:tid 216] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:12345 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Apr 18 16:54:50.558535 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 177468:tid 216] AH00455: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Apr 18 16:54:50.558535 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 177468:tid 216] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Nov 21 2013 20:13:01
[Mon Apr 18 16:54:50.558535 2016] [core:notice] [pid 177468:tid 216] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Apr 18 16:54:50.558535 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 177468:tid 216] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 175700
[Mon Apr 18 16:54:52.149738 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 175700:tid 228] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:12345 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Apr 18 16:54:52.617739 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 175700:tid 228] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:12345 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Apr 18 16:54:52.680139 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 175700:tid 228] AH00354: Child: Starting 1920 worker threads.
```

Could you determine where the problem is? I think it could have something to do with the worker threads, but I have tried everything in httpd.conf and nothing seems to work...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think your question might be better suited for ServerFault. That being said you are clearly opening too many concurrent threads. Have you tried limiting the number of concurrent requests?

Comment: Hi Technoh, do you mean inside the PHP script? Yes it runs normally 40 parallel requests. I reduced it to  1, the error does  now appear ~30-60 seconds later...

Comment: Are you sure you are closing the threads correctly? If you run apache status, does the number of open threads keep increasing?

Comment: Hi Technoh, do you know how I run apache status in XAMPP? My requests are ending inside the PHP script with "exit;" is there a better way to close a thread?

Comment: Sorry I don't know enough about XAMPP to help you there :( Maybe try your luck with ServerFault?

Comment: Hi Technoh, no problem, you already helped me. :) I will try different ways for closing my request, otherwise I will try ServerFault